# Python : Login to facebook to get user id... How to do it without a browser with python?

Tags: python

I just want to get the user id of the user... (15 digit user id of facebook users)
I am using this in a mobile application and want to avoid the web browser..

So.. can you suggest some sample code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/), do a GET request on `https://graph.facebook.com/<username>`

The returning JSON data will have the user id.

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.. But I wanted to do that with authentication.. well.. thanx for the reply.. as I already logged into facebook... via python script.. !!